# How to call local json file using http get method using angular 2 webpack

Tags: angular, http

I am using angular2 webpack and i want to call local json file using get method but its given me same above error

I tried above solution in my demo cli project its work fine for me but its same in webpack not working

Can any one please help me?

Comment: What error, and solution, are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Put your file (for example data.json) in the assets directory and then retrieve it using the path `/assets/data.json':

```
this.http.get('/assets/data.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Meir

You correct but if we using angular-cli but in webpack its not create assets folder its not work in my case.

But after many R&D i found answer is same like above but need to define that folder inside config details and put json file inside that folder in my case like

```
config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };
```

So in my case i need to put json file inside public folder.

Its resolve for me.