# How do you return data to your Angular app using proxy.conf.json?

Tags: json, angular, webpack, proxy

I am using proxy.conf.json as I develop my Angular application.

However I would like to, for a few endpoints, simply return a JSON object when called. Currently my proxy.conf file redirects to a locally running backend which returns these JSONs. However I'd rather not run the backend server and simply return the JSON from proxy.conf.json.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Create a json file in your asset folder and fetch it using http `get` method.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/44988056/5695162

Comment: @Vikas the reason I don't want to do this is because when the app is not in dev environment I want the file to actually come from the running server and not from a json file

Comment: proxying support is just a development thing. No use for building or deployment

Comment: I know. And according to your answer I'd have to manually change all the `http.get`s every time I want to build, which is not desirable

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible by using `proxy.conf.js` instead of `proxy.conf.json`. Then you can specify a bypass function where you can return a response directly. This is mentioned in the [angular-cli documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) for the proxy but it does not give many details. Here is a sample `proxy.conf.js` file to do it.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  '/api': {
    'target': 'http://localhost:5000',
    'bypass': function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
      switch (req.url) {
        case '/api/json1':
          const objectToReturn1 = {
            value1: 1,
            value2: 'value2',
            value3: 'value3'
          };
          res.end(JSON.stringify(objectToReturn1));
          return true;
        case '/api/json2':
          const objectToReturn2 = {
            value1: 2,
            value2: 'value3',
            value3: 'value4'
          };
          res.end(JSON.stringify(objectToReturn2));
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

You need to recheck the url in the bypass function because it is called for all `/api` requests and then you just directly return a response for the ones you want the others will still be redirected to the target address. You return true to tell the proxy the request finished.

Make sure to then specify the correct file when running `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

For returning JSON from `proxy.config.conf`, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do it.

One way would be to have a `baseApiUrl` in the `environment.ts` file as well `urlSuffix` set to `.json`. Then all of the API calls would have to be something like this: `enviroment.baseApiUrl` + `uri` + `environment.urlSuffix`. Then in `environment.prod.ts`, the `urlSuffix` would be an empty string. This is a hacky solution but would work.

**Alternative using HTTP_INTERCEPTORS**

A cleaner solution that leverages the framework, would be to use an `HttpInterceptor` with the `HttpClient` along with setting the `baseApiUrl` in the `environment.ts` file. This allows for different API endpoints per environment.

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
   apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/api',
   production: false
}
```

**development.interceptor.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class DevelopmentInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  let clonedRequest = null;

    if (!environment.production) {
      clonedRequest = request.clone({
        url: `${request.url}.json`
      });

      return next.handle(clonedRequest);
    }

    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
}
```

This class will intercept any http request made by the `HttpClient`. Using the properties in the `environment.ts` file, you can check if the current build is a production build. If it is, clone the request and append `.json` to it. Anything that is in the `assets` folder is accessible from the browser. Below is a sample file that maps to the url `http:localhost:4200/assets/api/test.json`.

**/src/assets/api/test.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Test Data"
}
```

Place this file in the assets directory and have the directory structure follow the endpoints of the actual API.

**test.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  private baseUrl = `${environment.apiBaseUrl}/test`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getTestData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

Import the `environment.ts` file here and set the base url to the `apiBaseurl` property. As long as you import the `environment.ts` file and not the `environment.prod.ts` file, this will work in all environments as the appropriate environment file will be read from when the app is built. So this url only has to be change in one place per environment.

[Angular CLI Build Targets & Environment Files](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files)

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TestService} from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.getTestData().subscribe(
      (testData) => console.log(testData)
    );
  }
}
```

Here the `TestService` is injected into the `AppComponent` and the `getTestData()` method is called to fetch data from the API. The `DevelopmentInterceptor` checks the `environment` and appends `.json` to the request. Then the data is logged to the console.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {DevelopmentInterceptor} from './development.interceptor';
import {TestService} from './test.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TestService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: DevelopmentInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Register the `TestService` and the `DevelopmentInterceptor` as providers.

Using this setup, `proxy.config.json` is not necessary.

For more information on `HttpInterceptors`, there is the Angular Documentation [Intercepting Http Requests & Responses](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses).

There is also a tutorial by Jason Watmore that does some more advanced things with this approach. [Angular 5 - Mock Backend Example for Backendless Development](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/12/15/angular-5-mock-backend-example-for-backendless-development)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Josh! I like your hacky solution, very creative. I would prefer avoiding using HTTP_INTERCEPTORS for this, especially since one of my calls to the backend happens before Angular is fully loaded. Still +1 though